# Angular form nothing on submit

Tags: angularjs, forms, submit

I'm currently trying to get a simple angular (v 1.4) form to submit data, but so far nothing happens when I click the submit button, I have the following html code;

```
<form name="requestForm">
  <textarea ng-model="specialOffer" name="specialOffer" rows="5" required></textarea>
  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="postOffer()">Submit</md-button>
</form>
```

And this is the model. Wat am I missing?;

```
angular.module('modulename').controller("codeController", function ($scope, $http) {    

$scope.postOffer = function () {
    if ($scope.specialOffer == null) {
        return false;
    }

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '#',
        data: {specialOffer: $scope.specialOffer}
    }).then(function successCallback(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $location.path('requests');
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        //Error
    });
};
```

});

Comment: Nothing wrong with the `<form>`, but you might consider change `url` to the desired target, `#` points to nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I took that out not to mention the URL weird. Any idea what could be the issue then?

Comment: Are you sure your #url responds to POST  and data in JSON format?

Comment: Well, I tried console.log('test'); instead of the $http request, but that doesn't work in the first place

Comment: Do you have any error in the Console? What happens if you put a breakpoint on the first line of your 'postOffer' function: `if ($scope.specialOffer == null) {` and click that button ?

Comment: Nothing does, it doesn't seem to actually get to the function..